# Как подключить одновременно через telethon свой аккаунт и своего бота

Tags: python, telethon

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить одновременно через telethon свой аккаунт и своего бота через один api_id и api_hash.

Мне необходимо отслеживать чужой канал используя сессию со своим аккаунтом, а отправлять в свой канал через бота.

Comment: Меня тоже интересует этот вопрос, подскажи, ты нашел решение?

Comment: я полностью ушел из telethon в pyrogram. Как сделать это на telethon - я не знаю(